# How do you wire a current sensor to multiple fans?

Tags: electrical, hvac, fans, blower, relay

I have two booster fans that I only want to run when the main HVAC blower fan is on.

Each fan will have its own speed controller.

How do I wire them both to the same [current sensor switch](https://vortexfanonline.com/collections/accessories/products/current-operated-solid-state-relays-for-switching-ac-circuits-with-5-minute-delay)? Should I just run two separate lines from each fan and connect them to the relay at the same place, or do I need to run a single cable from the relay with one fan online and one at the end of the run?

What part of the fan should the sensor connect to?

Comment: Are you talking about a current *sensor* with an analog output, or a current *switch* with a contact-closure output? What make and model is said sensor or switch, for that matter, and how many HP are said booster fans?

Comment: Switch. Here's a link: https://vortexfanonline.com/collections/accessories/products/current-operated-solid-state-relays-for-switching-ac-circuits-with-5-minute-delay

Comment: How many HP are your fans?

Comment: Between 2-3 amps each.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter if you run two separate cables to the two fans from the same point - two homeruns - or if you daisy chain, with one cable from the switch to the first fan, and a second cable from the first fan to the second.  Either way, they'll be in parallel electrically and the load through the switch is the same.

However, you do have another issue.  That switch in your link is handy because it's self powered, but it is rated for up to 2.5 amps at 120VAC, so it's really not up to running even one of those 3 amp fans directly.

You could use that current switch to operate the coil of a relay / contactor and have the contacts of that additional relay switch the fans.   There are zillions of such devices available, you'd just have to select one that's rated for the application (and of course you'd have to install it correctly).

You can also find current sensing relays that will combine both functions in one device.

Comment: Hm, that is very surprising since that is the exact switch the manufacturer recommends on their own website. They also sell it as a bundled kit see https://vortexfanonline.com/collections/kits/products/s-800-acs.

Comment: At this other page of their website http://vortexpowerfans.com/m/#./accessories they give more specs for it including "core current" of 50 amps while it is the switch rating that is 2.5 amps.

Comment: The fan manufacturer does not appear to be the switch manufacturer. 
 http://www.furisonelectric.com/Uploads/Download/2017-09-14/59ba0eee5f428.pdf

Comment: The "core current" is the current you can run through the switch - the sensed current - and the specs at the pdf in my previous comment say 40A, not 50A.

Comment: So if I bought the kit from the manufacturer it wouldn't work or would be a fire hazard?

Comment: If you bought the kit from the fan manufacturer, and the fan draws 3 amps as you say, then it would be running the switch at a current higher than it's rating.  Overloading things can overheat them and that can be a fire hazard.  However if you're lucky, it's possible the rating is very conservative, it may handle the fan current without a problem.  If you use a device within it's rating, you don't need luck.  (Although you do need a reputable brand quality product that can be trusted to perform at or above it's rating.)